# "invalid start byte" error reading parquet file using Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

I'm trying to use pandas to read a parquet file and get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb9 in position 16: invalid start byte
```

I couldn't find a way to send the encoding.
Here is my code:

```
from pandas import read_parquet
df = read_parquet("file.parquet")
print([col for col in df])
```

Comment: Which Python version are you using? Can you please paste the whole stracktrace? Are you using `pyarrow` as the Parquet engines and do you have the latest version of it installed?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6, with latest pandas and latest pyarrow which is the default engine used by read_parquet

Comment: Please also post the traceback